# Meaning of "hail to the king"

Tags: meaning, phrases

I can't translate that sentence, “hail to the king”. I've found something like “greetings to the king” but is this correct?

Comment: If the King is "King Taxi Ltd." (or something similar), then the role of subordination could be reversed!  ;-D

Comment: The Latin equivalent of *hail* in this sense is *ave*.  If you know the Catholic prayer that begins *Ave Maria* or the Roman salute *Ave Caesar*, then you'll understand the sense of this word (and possibly be easily able to find an equivalent in any other language with a Catholic tradition).

Comment: ... Hail Hydra!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nowadays, among it's meanings it has this one:

> **hail** *verb*
>   1. `[trans.]` **call out to (someone) to attract attention**: *the crew hailed a fishing boat.*
>   2. **signal (an approaching taxicab) to stop**: *she raised her hand to hail a cab.*

The Archaic usage is signalled as follows:

- exclamation *archaic*
  expressing greeting or acclaim: "*hail, Caesar!*"

Considering this, we can say that "Hail to the King!" can be both a way to express acclaim, praise to the King and express greeting.

But we even might be able to say that it can be both together. Deciding which one of these is the correct meaning depends on the context, as it usually happens with words with different acceptions.

---

The Etymology is this one:

> ORIGIN Middle English: from the obsolete adjective **hail** `[healthy]` (occurring in greetings and toasts, such as *wæs hæil*: see wassail ), from Old Norse *heill*.

which is related (it surprised me a bit) with *Whole* and its etymology:

> ORIGIN Old English *hāl*, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch **heel** and German **heil**, also to hail (`the quote I pasted above this one`). The spelling with wh- (reflecting a dialect pronunciation with w-) first appeared in the 15th cent.

Comment: +1 for the etymology -- I knew about _wassail_, but not about _whole_ -- that's nice.

Answer (score 9):

You need only look up the definition of [*hail*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hail):

> 1. to cheer, salute, or greet; welcome.
> 2. to acclaim; approve enthusiastically: *The crowds hailed the conquerors. They hailed the recent advances in medicine.*
> 3. to call out to in order to stop, attract attention, ask aid, etc.: to hail a cab.

In this case, the second definition is most appropriate, although the first may apply as well.

Perhaps the "to" in "hail to the king" is confusing you though -- *hail* can also serve as a noun denoting the act of hailing, so there's an implicit imperative here: "give your hail to the king."

Comment: @senderle: OP asked for the *meaning* of the sentence, not the etymology, so I think your answer is far more appropriate than @Alenanno's. As you say, it can easily be looked up in any online dictionary anyway, so your point about use of **to** is the only thing that gives the question any merit in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My main answer was not the Etymology :D I just added it because I thought it could add an additional level of completeness. But my answer to him is visible before the horizontal line. Your comment makes me think that maybe it's not that visible...

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I improved that part. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: I didn't mean to slight your answer as such; it contains many interesting (although peripheral) points. My intent was purely to complement @senderle on sticking to the core of the question. Remember that most times **Hail to the King** has ever been said in earnest, the monarch himself would not even have been present. @senderle's *acclaim; approve enthusiastically* exactly covers the normal context with minimal distraction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's ok, criticising makes me improve my answers :)

Comment: @Alenanno: I often think there should be two sets of answers, or at least two concurrent 'rating' systems. There's a 'best' answer addressing OP's question as succinctly as possible, and another kind of 'best' that makes interesting reading and enhances one's understanding of the area being covered. Of course, any assertions made in either *must* be correct/plausible, so you run more risk of stirring up dissention in the ranks by writing the second kind! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, writing more brings you the chance of being able to cover all the arguments required, but it sure puts you into the risk of receiving comments where people disagree with you :D

Comment: Thanks to senderle and Alenanno for their answers, both are great for me, and both answer my question, but Alenanno added more information useful to me, that's the reason I choose his answer. And for your information I asked this, after years of asking myself: Why Duke Nukem says "Hail to the King, baby?" :)

Comment: @LucasGabrielSánchez somehow this comment passed me by... what is it now, 8 years ago? But now, revisiting it, I think you might find [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Elvis/comments/78eoui/did_elvis_ever_say_hail_to_the_king_baby_and_any/) relevant.

Comment: @senderle thanks for that post, I knew about Bruce Cambpell saying "Hail to the King", but no the Elvis part