# English "whole" and Greek "holos"

Tags: etymology

Is the English adjective "whole" genealogically related in any way to the adjective "holos", which means "whole" in Koine (and possibly other varieties of Greek; I'm not sure), and has a similar pronunciation? If so, how are they related?

Comment: @z7sg, Why did you delete your post? I couldn't even upvote it!

Comment: @Third Idiot I leapt to the completely opposite and wrong conclusion!

Comment: Ah, well, you've corrected it, and its equally great -- in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They sound very similar but are actually [unrelated](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=85zS_w_AaP0C&lpg=PA148&ots=fJVG_5zv8L&dq=GK%20holos%20PIE%20etymology&pg=PA148#v=onepage&q&f=false).

The [Proto-Indo-European](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) root of *whole* is **koilas*.  From etymonline:

**whole** (adj.)

> O.E. hal "entire, unhurt, healthy," from P.Gmc. *khailaz "undamaged" (cf. O.S. hel, O.N. heill, O.Fris. hal, M.Du. hiel, Du. heel, O.H.G., Ger. heil "salvation, welfare"), from PIE ***koilas** (cf. O.S.C. celu "whole, complete;" see health). The spelling with wh- developed early 15c.

Greek *holos* is related to English *safe* and [several other words](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=holos&searchmode=none), including *Catholic*.

**safe** (adj.)

> late 13c., "uninjured, unharmed," from O.Fr. sauf, from L. salvus "uninjured, healthy, safe," related to salus "good health," saluber "healthful," all from PIE ***solwos** from base *sol- "whole" (cf. L. solidus "solid," Skt. sarvah "uninjured, intact, whole," Avestan haurva- "uninjured, intact," O.Pers. haruva-, Gk. **holos** "whole"). Meaning "not exposed to danger" is attested from late 14c.; of actions, etc., "free from risk," first recorded 1580s. Safe-conduct (late 13c.) is from O.Fr. sauf-conduit (13c.).

Comment: +1 for the great answer. I wish I could also give you another +1 for the link to etymonline.com !

Comment: Um, not great I messed um completely.  Fixed now. :) Etymonline is the greatest...

Comment: I'd like to link my answer in this question, since it's related: [Meaning of "hail to the king"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26982/meaning-of-hail-to-the-king/26985#26985).