# The hole and the whole

Tags: etymology

Why is **holism** named after some kind of *nothing* (a hole) and not after the *whole*, i.e. **wholism**?

That's the catchy way to ask the question. The serious way is: Does the "hole" have to do with the "whole" etymologically?

(Pun: A [howl](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howl) sounds best in a hole.)

Comment: It's an interesting question, but folks may be reacting negatively to the jokes obscuring the root of the question, or they may feel that it's too basic a question since it's easy to look up in an etymological dictionary.

Comment: I usually use the Online Etymology Dictionary, linked in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Holism*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=holism) is unrelated to *hole.* From the Online Etymology Dictionary:

> 1926, apparently by South African Gen. J.C. Smuts (1870-1950) in his book “Holism and Evolution” which treats of evolution as a process of unification of separate parts; from Greek *holos* “whole” (see *safe* (adj.)) + *-ism.*

Thus, *holism* is spelled like that because it's from a Greek word meaning “whole” that is spelled like *hole.* Oddly enough, [Greek *holos* is etymologically unrelated to either English word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28482/english-whole-and-greek-holos?rq=1).