# Are there some similar phrases or words like "hail" as in "hail the king"?

Tags: synonyms

"Hail" has meaning to praise, to greet. But replacing this words doesn't seem to fit well like "praise the king" , "greet the king". I want some words (or phrases ) which might fit well and sound good too. :)
Edit1 : I haven't done intense research on this word. Just visited some websites ( like thesaurus.org , dictionary.com, ([Meaning of "hail to the king"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26982/meaning-of-hail-to-the-king))) to find some similar words. But hardly any of those did sound good to me(like greet the king, praise the king ). I doubt imperative verbs would fit in well there.
Edit 2: I actually want words which will fit well in place "Hail" as in "Hail Hydra".  Fill this gap :  ____ hydra

Comment: Edit into your question your dictionary/synonym findings if you please!

Comment: "All honor to..."

Comment: 'Long live the King' is the traditional greeting.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Dave Wilton, an administrator at [Wordorigins.org...forums](http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/forums/viewthread/4533/),
 focuses the analysis: << The question is what grammatical category does ['hail'] fall into [here]. Is it an imperative to be well? Is it a hortatory subjunctive calling upon all present to wish the person well? Is it an optative subjunctive expressing a desire that the person be well? >> Formulaic subjunctives (not including 'Let ...' constructions) are rare. _God save the Queen!_

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth 's link is a good place to do research.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re looking for. (*Hail* seems to work well as written.)

Comment: @Lawrence . I'm actually curious to find some alternatives. Using Hail isn't a problem to me. I want more words like 'Hail'.

Comment: @AbinashDash That’s a bit too broad for this site’s format. Try narrowing it down by suggesting a sentence in which *hail* doesn’t work well. Also, try articulating some criteria to judge whether an answer would work for you. Use the [edit] link to put all that information straight into the question.

Comment: "give praise" or 'show praise' might work well for you.  "Make welcome to" is a way to say "greet" with some flourish to it.

Answer (score 0):

What about Exalt? Means to hold someone in very high regard. Sounds regal to my ear, and it's odd enough that I think it might be able to "blend in" in a way a common word like praise wouldn't.

You might also check thesaurus.com: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/exalt?s=t

Here are a couple other good ones from that list: bless, laud, acclaim, extol

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ***salute***.

From the Free Dictionary

```
    1. To greet or address with an expression of welcome, goodwill, or respect.
    ...
    3a. To honor formally and ceremoniously
```

Salute gives the connotation of acknowledging and giving respect to a superior in much the same way "hail" does.